# Read and write CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to read sentences in a csv file, convert them to lowercase and save in other csv file.

```
import csv
import pprint

with open('dataset_elec_4000.csv') as f:
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as ff:
        data = f.read()
        data = data.lower
        writer = csv.writer(ff)
        writer.writerow(data)
```

but I got error "_csv.Error: sequence expected". What should I do?
*I'm a beginner. Please be nice to me:)

Comment: `with open('dataset_elec_4000.csv', 'r') as f:` ?

Comment: Would you mind sharing a part of csv file so that I can share more customized answer?

Comment: `data = data.lower` does not return the lowercase string.  It returns the `lower` function object.  You need to CALL the function: `data = data.lower()`.

Comment: However, you are reading the ENTIRE FILE as one string.  You cannot use `csv.writer` to write the result, because you aren't reading rows.,  Just do:  `ff.write( f.read().lower())`.

Comment: The data is something like this {{"This case is just beautiful. I can't think of anything I don't like about it. I used a smaller-sized GTX 750 which allows you to see everything inside. A bigger video card blocks your view (probably by design)", "1.0"}, {"Very disappointed.  This item worked a time or two, but never consistently. I replaced the battery and it still wouldn't work.  I followed company instructions to make it work.  Don't waste your money.", "0.0"}, ...}

Comment: @TimRoberts It worked!!! Thank you so much:))))))))

Answer (score 0):

You need to read over your input CSV row-by-row, and for each row, transform it, then write it out:

```py
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)

    with open('dataset_elec_4000.csv', newline='') as f_in:
        reader = csv.reader(f_in)

        # comment these two lines if no input header
        header = next(reader)
        writer.writerow(header)

        for row in reader:
            # row is sequence/list of cells, so...
            # select the cell with your sentence, I'm presuming it's the first cell (row[0])
            data = row[0]

            data = data.lower()
            
            # need to put data back into a "row"
            out_row = [data]

            writer.writerow(out_row)
```

Answer (score -1):

Python contains a module called csv for the handling of CSV files. The reader class from the module is used for reading data from a CSV file. At first, the CSV file is opened using the open() method in ‘r’ mode(specifies read mode while opening a file) which returns the file object then it is read by using the reader() method of CSV module that returns the reader object that iterates throughout the lines in the specified CSV document.

```
import csv 
   # opening the CSV file 
with open('Giants.csv', mode ='r')as file: 
   # reading the CSV file 
csvFile = csv.reader(file) 
   # displaying the contents of the CSV file 
for lines in csvFile: 
print(lines)
```

Comment: He was already using the `csv` module.  Did you not see that?  He was just using it incorrectly.